# Need java equivalent of this c# code

Tags: java, c#, file, io

Learning file I/O in java, but cant seem to get java to recognize this format in a text document :

```
    A=1
    B=2
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Z=26
```

What i want is for the letters A through Z to be equal to the int counterpart, I've been able to do this in C# using this code:

```
        var dic = File.ReadAllLines(AplhabetFile)
                  .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
                  .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
```

but i can't seem to find its exact java equivalent anywhere.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: "*but i can't seem to find its exact java equivalent anywhere*", really ? [Reading a plain text file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) and [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java). Where did *you* look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with Streams:

```
Map<String, String> dic = Files.lines(Paths.get(AlphabetFile))
        .map(l -> l.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].trim(), s -> s[1].trim()));
```

Comment: thanks for the help.